# Laravel 5.2 add params to url

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass a value from a form(dropdwon) and append this value to a url.

My Routes are:

```
Route::get('menues/{city?}', 'PagesController@menue');
Route::post('/', 'PagesController@menue');
```

I have a simple form:

```
{!!Form::open(array('action' => 'PagesController@menue', 'method' => 'POST'))!!}
        {!! Form::select('city', array('heilbronn' => 'Heilbronn', 'stuttgart' => 'Stuttgart')) !!}
        {!!Form::submit('Senden')!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

And this Controller:

```
public function menue(Request $request, $city = null) {
  $searchinput = $request->input('city');

  $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
      $q->nowpublished();
  }]);

  if(!is_null($city) && !is_null(User::where('city', $city)->first())) {
      $restaurants->where('city', '=', $city);
  }

  $restaurants = $restaurants->get();    

  return view('pages.menues')->withRestaurants($restaurants)
                            //->withArticles($articles)
                            ->withCity($city)
                            ->withSearchinput($searchinput);                                
}
```

I need to append the value ($searchinput) from the previous page to show only entries for a particular city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your form `method` attribute to GET, then in your controller you can do follow:

```
public function menue(Request $request) {
  $city = $request->city;

  // bla-bla-bla

  if ( ! is_null($city) &&  && ! is_null(User::where('city', $city)->first()) {
    // bla-bla
  }

  // return
}
```

Comment: And change your routes to `Route::get('menues', 'PagesController@menue');`

Comment: Thank you astratyandmitry. Worked!